# How to use Cloud run from different project/domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have Cloud run function deployed on one different project than a webapp hosted on firebase.

In firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) it provides a way to call Cloud Run containers, but I can only specify `serviceId` and that service is not running in the same project as firebase container, so if I try to deploy it any way I get error 400.

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run service `service-name` does not exist in region `europe-north1` in this project.
```

I did not see a way to specify a project id in the rewrites config.

**Is there a way to call for firebase projects to call Cloud run containers from a different project?**

P.S. I am aware that I can call it over "regular" HTTPS however I would like to reduce the traffic and maybe even some billing.

Comment: AFAIK, Firebase is a set of API to wrap and simplify the use of Google Cloud. It's also an opiniated way to use Google Cloud. If you try to do unusual thing, it's possible that failed and you haven't built in workaround.

Comment: How am I being opinated by asking "is there a way"? If there is not I will figure it out. Only assumption I am making is that I have not read entire relevant documention.

Comment: He means **Firebase** is opinionated. English is his second language. That means Firebase has a certain way of doing things and what it supports. In other words, use the Google Cloud APIs instead.

Comment: Oh... Well yah it seams that API is incomplete.

Comment: "That's not a bug, it's a feature!" Actually, incomplete could be a choice by the team. (And sorry for my approximative english!)

Comment: It is possible its a choice, sometimes its a choice to put docs somewhere else. 
(No worries, a) I get I am not a native English speaker either b) It's bit on my for not figuring out... *one should write to stackoverflow past midnight* :D)

Comment: Functionality to specify a Cloud Run service hosted in another project from a Firebase hosted web app does not seem to be available based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) out there. You can submit a feature request for it through Google’s [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) portal.